# method 'range' of object '_global' failed vba access

Tags: excel, vba, range

problem with correct statement

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B:B-B5"), a)
```

i want to select an entire column minus a cell in VBA.
how can I do this?

Comment: `CountIf` works with a Contiguous Range. AFAIK you cannot subtract a cell from the Range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a helper function for this:

```
Function CountIfExcept(from As range, except As range, criteria As String)
    CountIfExcept = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(from, criteria) - Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(except, criteria)
End Function
```

Usage:

```
totalCount = CountIfExcept(Range("B:B"), RANGE("B5"), "some condition")
```

Comment: You might want to Remove the Extra `)` from the Usage Example.